# Implementing if-else with the C preprocessor

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I've been attempting to write a C macro which would take a condition as input, and output something only if that condition evaluated true.

Using the constructs from http://jhnet.co.uk/articles/cpp_magic I attempted to implement a simpler version of this, whereby there would always be an output value but it would differ depending on how the condition evaluated. I used the IF_ELSE macro from that article:

```
#define SECOND(a, b, ...) b

#define IS_PROBE(...) SECOND(__VA_ARGS__, 0)
#define PROBE() ~, 1

#define CAT(a,b) a ## b

#define NOT(x) IS_PROBE(CAT(_NOT_, x))
#define _NOT_0 PROBE()

#define BOOL(x) NOT(NOT(x))

#define IF_ELSE(condition) _IF_ELSE(BOOL(condition))
#define _IF_ELSE(condition) CAT(_IF_, condition)

#define _IF_1(...) __VA_ARGS__ _IF_1_ELSE
#define _IF_0(...)             _IF_0_ELSE

#define _IF_1_ELSE(...)
#define _IF_0_ELSE(...) __VA_ARGS__
```

For straightforward integer inputs, this is indeed adequate:

```
IF_ELSE(0)(1)(0)
```

and

```
IF_ELSE(0x7F)(1)(0)
```

evaluated to 0 and 1 respectively.

However:

```
IF_ELSE(6 < 7)(1)(0)
```

and

```
IF_ELSE(6 > 7)(1)(0)
```

both output 1, presumably because the ~ operator is applied to the 6 in both cases. I'm afraid this level of macro magic is a long way ahead of anything I've tried before with the preprocessor, and I haven't been able to work out a way to solve this on my own. Can anyone help?

Comment: No, this does not work at all. Your `IF_ELSE` already fails with `00` or `0x0`.

Comment: There is no way out. What you want cannot be done. The preprocessor evaluates integer expressions *only within* the conditional inclusion statements (#if and the like)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala You're quite right, replacing the 0 with 00 or 0x00 does cause the IF_ELSE to output 1. I didn't realise that would be the case.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get the preprocessor to evaluate constant expressions outside of the context of an `#if` directive.

Comment: But why you do this? Too many macros make code less readable.